# Count and Group By Semantics: Why are these two different?

Tags: sql

So I'm pretty new to SQL and have the following two queries:

```
WITH contributions AS (
  SELECT cc.cand_id, cc.cmte_id
    FROM committee_contributions as cc
    GROUP BY cc.cand_id, cc.cmte_id
)
SELECT c.cand_id, COUNT(c.cand_id) as count
  FROM contributions as c
  GROUP BY c.cand_id 
  ORDER BY count DESC
```

and

```
SELECT cc.cand_id, count(cc.cmte_id) as count
  FROM committee_contributions as cc
  GROUP BY cc.cand_id
  ORDER BY count DESC
```

Which give me two totally different outputs. From my understanding, the first one selects two columns and groups them by cand_id and then cmte_id, then counts the number of occurrences of each cand_id.The second one counts the number of cmte_id's associated with each cand_id. In my mind the second one should be the same as the first. Could anyone enlighten me as to the difference?

Also, is there a better way to write the first statement without using the WITH or a nested query?

Answer (score 0):

The first query is counting the number of **distinct** occurrences of cmte_id per cand_id (including nulls, if there are any), the second is counting the total number of records per cand_id where cmte_id is not null.

Answer (score 0):

NO. They are two very different things. In the first one, you are taking a count of `cand_id` and in the second, `cmte_id`

Also, in the first query, the rollup(grouping) happens twice. So count per `cand_id` will be lesser than in the second one.

You could replace your first query with the one below, which does essentially same:

```
SELECT cand_id, cmte_id, COUNT(DISTINCT cand_id) as [count]
FROM contributions
GROUP BY cand_id, cmte_id 
ORDER BY [count] DESC
```

But, if you strictly don't need the `cmte_id` column, you would need to use nested query.